# When I bring my app to the foreground doesn´t load the last activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

I'm getting an unexpected behavior:

- Activity A = Launcher activity
- Activity B = It's started from a notification

When I have closed the app and open it from the notification, the Activity B is started.

So, when I click on HOME button, the app navigates to the Activity A.
Then, I push the BACK button and the app goes to background and I get the Android main screen.

This is OK, but if I open the recent apps menu and select again my app, it loads the Activity B instead Activity A as I expect. I don't really know what is happening.

The intent set in the notification builder is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

In Activity B I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: does that happens every time or only after if you click the push and load the app ?\

Comment: Only when I start Activity B from the push notification.

Comment: use `.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` and tell me if it works !

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which fit in what I'm expecting.
When I receive a notification I create a new Task Stack with my mainActivity on the top:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ActivityB.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now, I can also remove the overrided check for HOME button in the Activity B:

```
// This can be now removed
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that the task which is in the list of recent tasks was started from the `Notification` with `ActivityB` as the root `Activity`. If you choose this task from the list of recent tasks, Android will bring the existing task to the foreground. However, if the task has no active activities in it (all the activities have been finished), then Android starts the root `Activity` from that task again.

You need to prevent the app from being added to the list of recent tasks **if it is started** from a `Notification`. You can do that by adding:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

to the manifest entry for `ActivityB`.

Comment: What you say makes sense. How can I exclude from rencents this Activity only when it starts from a Notification?

Comment: By doing what I said. Since your normal launcher `Activity` is `ActivityA`, the app will show up in the list of recents when it is started with `ActivityA`, but not when it is started with `ActivityB`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Your solution works. But it would be great if I can get the main Activity from rencents instead.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to have your `Notification` start the main `Activity` and pass it some "extras" so that it knows to immediately launch `ActivityB` (passing the extras along to `ActivityB`. In this case, your task will always start with `ActivityA`, so you can leave it in the "recents" list. However, if I recall, this causes another problem, because if you return to your app from the "recents" list, Android will start `ActivityA` just like it did the first time (ie: with the "extras") so that it thinks it is being launched from a `Notification`...

Comment: In that case, you also need to check if `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` is set in `ActivityA` and then you know that the app was started from the "recents" list and you can ignore the "extras" as it isn't really being launched from a Notification.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll try it. And what do you think about the solution I posted where I create a new Task Stack?

Comment: If your app is already running and you click on the `Notification` that you constructed with `TaskStackBuilder`, the task is reset (this means that whatever the user was doing is lost because all the activities in the existing task are finished. If that is OK for you, then you can probably use your solution. I stay far away from `TaskStackBuilder` for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag instead, which will only reorder the activities, instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` which will remove other activities on top of it.

For example, when using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

consider a task consisting of four activities: `A, B, C, D`. If `D` calls `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that resolves to the component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the history stack, with this resulting order: `A, C, D, B`. This flag will be ignored if `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is also specified.

you can refer to this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: I think this won't solve the problem. If the app is close, I have no tasks to reorder so I'll get the same behavior, right?